# Excel macro infinite loop keeps asking for user's input and can't "step into" to debug

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a few macros to do the following in Excel 2010:
1. Upon creating a new worksheet ask for what the user wants to name his/her worksheet and sets the new worksheet to the name provided; calls Sort_Active_Book and Rebuild_TOC in order
2. Sort_Active_Book: Asks the user if he/she wants to sort the workbook's worksheets in ascending/descending order and proceeds to do so.
3. Rebuild_TOC: Deletes the Table of Contents page and rebuilds it based on all the worksheets in the workbook minus the TOC itself.

My problem is Excel keeps asking me to input the name of the new worksheet to be created and does not progress any further in the code. I notice it manages to create the named worksheet and asks me if I would like to sort ascending or descending but then proceeds to ask me again the name of the new worksheet. Could anyone please point out how to fix this and provide a code fix (if possible) please?

#### What I have already

This code portion is from *ThisWorkbook*, this is what prompts the user for the name of the worksheet upon creation.

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)

    Dim sName As String
    Dim bValidName As Boolean
    Dim i As Long

    bValidName = False

    Do While bValidName = False
        sName = InputBox("Please name this new worksheet:", "New Sheet Name", Sh.Name)
            If Len(sName) > 0 Then
            For i = 1 To 7
                sName = Replace(sName, Mid(":\/?*[]", i, 1), " ")
            Next i
            sName = Trim(Left(WorksheetFunction.Trim(sName), 31))
            If Not Evaluate("ISREF('" & sName & "'!A1)") Then bValidName = True
        End If
    Loop

    Sh.Name = sName

    Call Sort_Active_Book
    Call Rebuild_TOC

End Sub
```

These two macros are in "Module 1":

```
Sub Sort_Active_Book()

    Dim TotalSheets As Integer
    Dim p As Integer
    Dim iAnswer As VbMsgBoxResult

    ' Move the TOC to the begining of the document.
Sheets("TOC").Move Before:=Sheets(1)

    ' Prompt the user as to which direction they wish to
    ' sort the worksheets.
    iAnswer = MsgBox("Sort Sheets in Ascending Order?" & Chr(10) & "Clicking No will sort in Descending Order", vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton1, "Sort Worksheets")
    For TotalSheets = 1 To Sheets.Count
        For p = 2 To Sheets.Count - 1

    ' If the answer is Yes, then sort in ascending order.
            If iAnswer = vbYes Then
                If UCase$(Sheets(p).Name) = "TOC" Then
                   Sheets(p).Move Before:=Sheets(1)
                ElseIf UCase$(Sheets(p).Name) > UCase$(Sheets(p + 1).Name) Then
                   Sheets(p).Move After:=Sheets(p + 1)
            End If

    ' If the answer is No, then sort in descending order.
            ElseIf iAnswer = vbNo Then
            If UCase$(Sheets(p).Name) = "TOC" Then
                Sheets(p).Move Before:=Sheets(1)
            ElseIf UCase$(Sheets(p).Name) < UCase$(Sheets(p + 1).Name) Then
                Sheets(p).Move After:=Sheets(p + 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next p
    Next TotalSheets
End Sub
```

and

```
Sub Rebuild_TOC()

    Dim wbBook As Workbook
    Dim wsActive As Worksheet
    Dim wsSheet As Worksheet

    Dim lnRow As Long
    Dim lnPages As Long
    Dim lnCount As Long

    Set wbBook = ActiveWorkbook

    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    ' If the TOC sheet already exist delete it and add a new worksheet.
On Error Resume Next
    With wbBook
        .Worksheets(“TOC”).Delete
        .Worksheets.Add Before:=.Worksheets(1)
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set wsActive = wbBook.ActiveSheet
    With wsActive
        .Name = “TOC”
        With .Range(“A1:B1”)
            .Value = VBA.Array(“Table of Contents”, “Sheet # – # of Pages”)
            .Font.Bold = True
        End With
    End With

    lnRow = 2
    lnCount = 1

    ' Iterate through the worksheets in the workbook and create sheetnames, add hyperlink
    ' and count & write the running number of pages to be printed for each sheet on the TOC.
    For Each wsSheet In wbBook.Worksheets
        If wsSheet.Name <> wsActive.Name Then
            wsSheet.Activate
            With wsActive
                .Hyperlinks.Add .Cells(lnRow, 1), “”, _
                SubAddress:=”‘” & wsSheet.Name & “‘!A1”, _
                TextToDisplay:=wsSheet.Name
                lnPages = wsSheet.PageSetup.Pages().Count
                .Cells(lnRow, 2).Value = “‘” & lnCount & “-” & lnPages
            End With
            lnRow = lnRow + 1
            lnCount = lnCount + 1
        End If
    Next wsSheet

    wsActive.Activate
    wsActive.Columns(“A:B”).EntireColumn.AutoFit

    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new sheet with sub Rebuild_TOC. Causing the newsheet macro to run again.

You will need to avoid running the newsheet macro by adding a enableevents = false and true surrounding your code when creating a new sheet for your TOC. The rest of your code appears to be working as you want it to.

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
With wbBook
    .Worksheets("TOC").Delete
    .Worksheets.Add Before:=.Worksheets(1)
End With
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Why would you want to delete the TOC worksheet, why not just update it?

Comment: I am deleting the page because it seemed simpler rather than adding in code to find where to place the new link on the Table of Contents page. The TOC sheet needs to be alphanumerically sorted.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, with adding the `EnableEvents`, that should fix it, tested it multiple times on my own and it ran all the way through without a problem.

Comment: I have given this snip-it of code a try and it now points out there is a syntax error at the row "With.Range("A1:B1")" and the row below it, ".Value = VBA.Array("Table of Contents", "Sheet # - of Pages")", saying "compile error: expected: list separator or )". Does anyone have any input on this error message?

Comment: That was something else there caused a problem when I copied your code over, the quotes are weird. Once I changed them to standard quotes it fixed it. They were only in that sub for some reason.

Comment: sorry, didn't realize the VBA.Array, just make that `Array()`

Comment: I believe you were right on the money when you mentioned those quotes, I am changing them now and as I do the lines are turning black from red.

Comment: I believe I had stated that this was an Excel macro, doesn't the macro need the "VBA." in front of the Array?

Comment: Nope it doesn't need that. You did note in the tags that this was excel-vba. Even still, it should work either way, the only changes I made were updating all of the quotes in the code since they were italicized and `EnableEvents`.

Comment: BOOYA! It works! I appreciate the help @histerical, it is working smoothly ^-^ Marked as answer despite some of it being in these comments.

Comment: Thanks! Glad I was able to help.